# Why JSONEncoder works differently with Dictionary of enum keys?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, enums, encodable

When I use `JSONEncoder` for structure like this:

```
struct A: Encodable {
    var items: [String : Int]
}

let a = A(items: ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3])
```

I get `items` property as JSON object as expected: `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`. But when I use enumeration for key like this:

```
enum E: String, Encodable {
    case a, b, c
}

struct A: Encodable {
    var items: [E : Int]
}

let a = A(items: [.a: 1, .b: 2, .c: 3])
```

I get `items` as JSON array: `["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]`. This is very confusing and also I can not find any documentation about this behaviour.

There is a way to have this code working by wrapping such dictionary into structure and implement Encodable protocol, but maybe there is simple way to do this?

```
struct A {
    var items: W
}

struct W {
    var items: [E : Int]
}

extension W: Encodable {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: @koen my enum already encodable because I use `String` as parent type. I don't have problems with encoding dictionary into JSON. My question is about why I'm getting different JSON types.